# how to get MVC Enum Dropdownlist value in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, enums

I'm new to MVC. I have a dropdownlist that I created using enum values that works perfectly. However, I want to get the dropdownlist value(MINITRUCK,TRUCK,BIGTRUCK,VAN) , I am unable to get the value the user selects from the dropdownlist into the database table (SQLserver) and the database table column format for the selects is varchar(20)
what's wrong in my code? how to get the dropdownlist select in  control ?
Here is the code....

MODEL\Enumlist.cs :

```
namespace InfoMIS.Models
public enum CarType 
{

    MINITRUCK,
    TRUCK,
    BIGTRUCK,
    VAN
}
```

MODEL\application.cs :

```
 [Display(Name = "Car Type")]
 [StringLength(10)]
 public string CModel { get; set; }
```

my view :

```
<div class="col-xl-4 col-md-6 col-12">
      <div class="row">
           <div class="col-xl-4 col-md-4 col-12 form-title">
                 @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CModel)
           </div>
           <div class="col-xl-8 col-12">
           @Html.DropDownList("CarType", new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(InfoMIS.Models.CarType))), "please choose one", new { @class = "rwd-select" })
          </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

put this code in your view

```
@{
var carTypes = Enum.GetValues(typeof(CarType)).OfType<CarType>().Select(m => new SelectListItem { Text = m, Value = m }).ToList();
}
....
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CModel, @carTypes, "Select type", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: how to get select  value in control ?

Comment: @You have to create a post action. Can you show your model pls?

Comment: I have try to add your code in my view,but now the page is cannot work

Comment: @georgetovrea Before trying to write some code , you have to find and learn an MVC tutorial to understand  how MVC is working. It is impossible to teach you in comments.

Comment: I have to show my mode,can you help me?